# Sharepoint adds unneded code to uploaded files

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Playing with SharePoint 2010 and have noticed a very strange behavior.
When uploading html or css file to the document library (by user and by C# code), SharePoint automatically adds such code into the files:

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
******************************
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```

That's really undesired behavior, cause uploaded files will be used later for validation purposes by custom library.

Is there any possibility to avoid such behavior at SharePoint side? It's not desired to modify the validation lib.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/30971) is related to your case as well? Though no designer in your case, maybe uploading the file makes it "Unghosted" as well.

Comment: In my experience this should not happen to css files, but when you upload a file with html or htm extension and not having html tag inside it, it generates this tags at botton. To overcome this, we use txt extension when uploading files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is done.
Two variants:

1. If items are being added through the code - you can modify the file format to your custom (for example prjectNamehtml) before uploading it. Then in event receiver (item adding event) - check if this is our custom format - change format back to html. In this case described code won't be added to file.
2. This variant is more universal and will also work for manual upload of file through the portal. It's needed to use event receiver where in constructor we should get current Http Context and save it into variable. Then in ItemAdding - we should check, if this is .html file - get it's content through the context and reject creation of source file. Received content should be used to save file via code and process it as it's in the 1st variant.